Looking for a movie similar to Before Sunset, but set in the USA with two young blonde actors
I am in need of help. I'm trying so hard to remember the title or the actor's name of this indie movie and I just can't remember much.
It was a small movie with two young actors, both female and male were beautiful kinds of boho blonde typical people. They met while traveling (I think) and had this not so platonic friendship. They lived apart and met at random places throughout the movie, one of which was the USA. The girl had an Asian boyfriend and was considering going away with him.
It just had this bittersweet atmosphere about the main protagonist's relationship. Kind of like Before Sunset but set in the USA.
The actor looks a lot like Natalie Portman, but blonde, or even Joakin Phoenix. I think the movie gained attention through Sundance.
It definitely was released after 2004. (I know I'm not helping)

May be A Lot Like Love

No,unfortunately it's now. None of the protagonists where a list names.
